# Div not showing in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm having trouble with two of my divs not showing in Safari. They show fine on Chrome and Firefox. The buttons with the class .phquote and .designquote are not showing on the first page. Here is the link to my website to inspect http://shellhammersara.se

I've tried to see if anything is wrong with the images, but that isn't it. I tried taking them out and just added a background color to the div and it still wouldn't show.

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Below is my code:

HTML

```
<main>

      <div id="homebanner">

        <div class="bannerbuttons">

            <a href="photography.html" class="phquote"></a>
            <a href="myfavorites.html" class="designquote"></a>
            <a href="contact.php" class="contactbtn"></a>

        </div>

    </div>

    </main>
```

CSS

```
#homebanner {
    background-image: url("Images2/home.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: -33px;
}
    .contactbtn {
    display: none;
}
    .bannerbuttons {
    width: 55%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.phquote {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 45%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("/Images2/ph-quote-400.png");
    -o-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
}

.phquote:hover {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("Images2/ph-quote-hover-400.png");
-o-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
}

.designquote {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 45%;
    margin-top: 190px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("Images2/design-quote-400.png");
    -o-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
}

.designquote:hover {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("Images2/design-quote-hover-400.png");
    -o-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;

}
```

Comment: You need to know that no browser has needed those vendor prefixes in many, many years and versions. You can safely remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add "height:100%" to .bannerbuttons class

Answer (score 1):

In my case,sometimes  when using flexbox safari messes up.

Giving flex a value solved the problem for me, e.g. flex: 1 0 auto